# Max-width and rounding errors in IE8 & IE9?

Tags: css

I've got a list of images floating in a gallery sort of style. The problem occurs when one of the images is not the same size as the others. All images, except one in my example, are 235x187 pixels. The odd image has a width of 666px and a height of 530px. My list items have a fixed width set to 235px, and the images have a max-width set to 100%. The aspect ratio of the smaller images and the larger one are the same (down to the fourth decimal).

As you can see in the example, the max-width limits all the images to a width of 235 pixels, and everything looks ok except in IE9 & IE8 (IE7 seems fine), where the fourth image floats up beside the larger, yellow image. This happens even though the browser reports the larger image to be of the same calculated height as the other images.

So my question would be: what is going on in IE9 & 8? Is it a rounding error, or is it IE not repainting the list after it has recalculated the css width of the larger image?

Have a look at the example over at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99chG/1/

Comment: it's IEs compatibility mode... *puke*
Try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge" />`

Comment: You could be onto something, but I've tried this fiddle in IE, setting the Browser mode to IE8 & the Document Mode to IE8. Then set the browser to IE9 mode in the same manner. Are you saying that there's a difference in the result of using the meta tag over changing the rendering mode by hand in the web developer? Of course I would of course use the meta tag in the case of a production site, but just asking to see if there's any difference...

Comment: the problem: in intern networks the IE uses the compatibility mode. the link you posted worked fine in IE 9 with IE 9-rendering but failed badly when I changed it to IE 9-compatibility mode. You can try it in the tools - F12 ;)

Comment: I did try it exactly just as you said. Here's a screenshot illustating the result. Do you set the rendering mode the same as I do? http://grab.by/dBDo

Comment: Adding to the above, I am actually setting the meta tag on the development site. Unfortunately I can't share the URL at the moment, but that site is showing the same error in IE9 & IE8

Comment: my fault. It should be `IE=edge`, sorry

Comment: I'm using the following meta tag on the dev. site: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> Still the same problem though.

Comment: Here's a complete html (same example as on jsFiddle) document with the included meta tag. Still the same issue in IE9 & 8: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/365267/index.html

Answer (score 2):

it's working

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style>
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

110% working we have to use java script for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/zwAkx/

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: Um, the question wasn't about rounded corners at all in the first place :) Sorry if I wasn't able to make myself clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe make sure your doctype is set-up correctly.

If it's lower case then it might not work. It has to be